# How to dismiss view controller if it presented from app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm trying to figure out deeplinking. I have successfully gotten my app to recognize and run code I want it to depending on the path in the URL. Now when I present a View, it shows but can't get the back button or any way to dismiss it to work. Here's the code in my appdelegate:

```
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        BuyPremiumViewController *premiumViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BuyPremium"];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:premiumViewController];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The reason I use a UINavigationController is to have the nav title and back button show in the presented view. Thing is, it is not working. Here is the code that runs when the back button is tapped in the presented view:

```
- (void)backButton {
 NSLog(@"this ran"); //check if actually ran
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Being at it for a hours now, help?

Comment: The opposite of `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is `dismissViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: Your `backButton` code does nothing, because `premiumViewController` IS the `rootViewController` of your `navigationController`.  so popToRootVC does nothing.  As @rmaddy says, use `[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]`.

Comment: I feel like I saw this question earlier this week.

Comment: thanks guys. DismissViewController worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
- (void)backButton
 {
     NSLog(@"this ran"); //check if actually ran
     [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```